# Получение данных из контрола во вью модель

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть у меня GroupBox:

```
<GroupBox Header="Создание Задачи"
                  Margin="5,5,5,5"
                  FontWeight="Bold"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Visibility="{Binding IsCreate, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibleConverter}}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label Content="Название Задачи"
                       FontStyle="Italic"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Margin="2,3,2,0"/>
                <TextBox
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsCreate}"
                    Margin="2,0,2,3"
                    FontWeight="Normal"
                    Text="{Binding NewUserTask.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <Label Content="Группа"
                       FontStyle="Italic"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Margin="2,3,2,0"/>
                <TextBox   
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsCreate, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Margin="2,0,2,3"
                    FontWeight="Normal"
                    Text="{Binding NewUserTask.Group, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
                <Label Content="Описание Задачи"
                       FontStyle="Italic"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Margin="2,3,2,0"/>
                <TextBox
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsCreate}"
                    Margin="2,0,2,3"
                    Height="110"
                    FontWeight="Normal"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    Text="{Binding NewUserTask.Description, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <Label Content="Статус"
                       FontStyle="Italic"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Margin="2,3,2,0"/>
                <ComboBox
                        IsEnabled="{Binding IsCreate, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        ItemsSource="{local:EnumValues {x:Type model:MyEnum}}"
                        SelectedValuePath="Value"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Display"
                        SelectedValue="{Binding NewUserTask.Status, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    Margin="2,0,2,3" />
                <Label Content="Планируемая Дата Завершения"
                       FontStyle="Italic"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Margin="0,3,0,0"/>
                <DatePicker
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsCreate}"
                    Margin="2,0,2,5"
                    SelectedDate="{Binding NewUserTask.DueDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <StackPanel
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button
                       Content="Отмена"
                       Margin="5,5,5,25"
                       Height="20"/>
                    <Button 
                       Content="Сохранить"
                       Margin="25,5,20,25"
                       Height="20"
                       Command="{Binding Create2Command}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>
```

и есть объект на который идет биндинг NewUserTask {get; set;}, но когда я пытаюсь обработать данные с вью части, то получается проблема, т.к. NewUserTask приходит пустым. Внимание вопрос : Как вытащить данные из моих контролов?

Comment: Вы должны проиницилизировать поле `NewUserTask` сами, в конструкторе ViewModel, например.

Comment: А приведите пример, как вы устанавливаете `DataContext`.

Comment: DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();